# Qt - drawing image on image using another image as a mask

Tags: qt, drawing, transparency, mask

Here's the issue at hand. I need to be able to pick a background (an image showing an object, let's say, a starship model). I want to be able to apply various previously prepared textures to various areas on it, as some kind of a "colour your own object" app, but without the need to prepare dozens of individual segments.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is one, newbie way to do it. We have those images:

[image: Original photo]
[image: Alternative, quick photoshop]

Two kind of different versions, an original photo and a quickly Photoshopped one. Let's say we only want the Borg-ish green deflector and warp nacelle from the second picture, without the odd pink hull. You have to have a mask, basicly an image of an equal resolution (or at least the same aspect ratio, which you can reliably scale to image's resolution), with the area filled with color (or whatever else), and transparent area everywhere else. As the mask, I've used a few strokes of brush on an empty layer, set to overlay mode, and then saved as PNG, with transparency. And this is how the code went:

First, import images.

```
QPixmap background("orig.png"); //import base image
//import alt version/texture/whatever you want, anything will work with a good mask
QPixmap element("alt.png");  
QPixmap mask("deflector.png"); //mask. Just nacelles and deflector.
```

Then, isolate the area that interests us from alt version

```
QPainter painter(&element);
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn);
painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, mask.width(), mask.height(), mask);
```

And finally draw it onto the target object.

```
QPainter inter(&background);
inter.drawPixmap(0, 0, element);

ui->label->setPixmap(background);
```

The result:
[image: Result]

This method respects any and all transparency you could've done in Photoshop or another image editing software.

Simple, but an effective solution, for when your app has to work with graphics prepared by someone else, elsewhere.